# Open a link in electron created a new browser window How to Apply set Browser window properties on that window?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have one main Electron window which is loaded by loadURL. In that window we a different
a-tag which automatically created a new BrowserWindow with default setting. how can we change the Browserwindow properties on that window like.

```
new BrowserWindow({
 width: width,
 show: true,
 height: height,
 frame: false,
 transparent: true,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`setWindowOpenHandler`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler) method to intercept the window launch and configure the properties:

```
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    return {
        action: "allow",
        overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
            width: 100,
            frame: false,
            // etc.
        }
});
```

Note this handler will fire for all windows opened from your main window, so you might want to check the `details.disposition` property or figure out in some other way if you want to mess with the window configuration (e.g. `window.open` will also trigger this)